# How to get all the elements from cloud firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

Iam coding an eCommerce app and from my admin panel app I uploaded product images, name price, and so on to cloud firestore.

looks like this

[image]

I want to take this information and make a grid view to show the products in my app. How can i do that..

Please some one help me with exact code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void getData()async
{
DocumentSnapshot snapshot= await Firestore.instance.collection('collectionName').document('documentName').get();
var document= snapshot.data;
    String category=document['category'];
    String id=document['id'];
    String name=document['name'];
    int quantity=document['quantity'];
    List<String> images=List.from(document['images']);

}
```

Now use these variables to show your data.

for gridview of images:-

1.) create grid tiles

```
List<GridTile> newGridTile=[];
    images.forEach((image) {newGridTile.add(GridTile(
          child: Image.network(image),
    ));});
```

2,) show this grid

```
GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              childAspectRatio: 1.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 1.5,
              crossAxisSpacing: 1.5,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: newGridTile,
            ),
```

and design it further by adding your category and other fields to it.

If you want to get all the items i.e all documents then:-

```
void getData()async
        {
        QuerySnapshot snapshot=await Firestore.instance.collection('collectionName').getDocuments();
    snapshot.documents.forEach((document){
    category=document['category'];
.
.
.
.
//similarly for all other fields like in the fist code of the answer.
    });
        }
```

Comment: I have edited the code now replace the collectionName with your collection's name and documentName with your document id i.e. one starting with 2a3b0... in your pic

Comment: If it helped you then pls accept it as the answer.

Comment: bro theres still problems..I have get the document snapshots..You can see that there is 3 images in images list. What i want is it have to show the first image and over them it has to show the prod name, price, shop...i want the two product details to be shown likw that in grid view...

Comment: You mean you want to have the image in background and over that image you want to show name and other details?